# Sql query to get Total in columns

Tags: sql

whats the SQL Query to get the final row?

```
Region   Country        City    Population

Africa   Ghana          Accra   11200
Africa   Ghana          Nzma    1186
Africa   Ghana          Bole    160
Africa   Ghana          3       12546
```

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using ? From where are you querying ? are you getting already de result and just want to make it bold ? Add more details to your questions so someone can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Table.Region, Table.Country, Sum(Table.[Population]) AS [Sum Population]
FROM Table
GROUP BY Table.Region, Table.Country;
```

'Table is your Table Name

Answer (score 4):

Using TSQL, you can try:

```
SELECT Region, Country, COUNT(City), SUM(Population) FROM TableName
GROUP BY Region, Country
```

Comment: Region   Country        City    Population

Africa   Ghana          Accra   11200
Africa   Ghana          Nzma    1186
Africa   Ghana          Bole    160                           Africa   Kenya          Nairobi 12000                               How to group by region?